# None of the text fields are showing variable values AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My text fields were showing everything perfectly until I got rid of a newly added function (worked fine before it was added), now they're blank. Tracing the results in the events holds the right values it's just not showing up in the text boxes.

I'm coding in the timeline because I haven't quite grasped external functions just yet. Here's the code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var earner:Number = 1;
var price:Number = 2;
var multi:Number = 1;
var clickstr:Number = 1;

multitxt.text = String(multi);
output.text = String(earner);
pricetxt.text = String(price);

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buyClick);
earn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, earnClick);

function buyClick(Event:MouseEvent):void
{
    clickstr = 1;
    if (earner >= price)
    {
        earner = earner - price;
        price = price * 1.13375;
        multi = multi + 0.025;
        multitxt.text = String(multi);
    }
    output.text = String(earner);
    pricetxt.text = String(price);
}

function earnClick(Event:MouseEvent):void
{
earner = earner + (clickstr * multi);
output.text = String(earner);
pricetxt.text = String(price);
}
```

Thanks, I appreciate any and all responses.

Comment: I don't see any errors in the code. Check if your text fields are using embedded fonts, if yes, clear the flag on them and test again.

Comment: I changed them all from 'Classic Text' to 'TLF Text' and it has fixed it. I don't understand how that plays any part as it was always on Classic Text and worked. Ah well, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, TLF text is not a good idea to use. It was introduced in one version and dropped soon after. It is not currently supported by the Flash IDE.

Instead continue using the Classic Text, just make sure the font is embedded. Though I can't be 100% certain that's the issue.

Comment: I've changed them back and embedded the fonts. I tested it before the fonts were embedded, and it worked again. Much to my surprise.